# How to backup POA based ethereum private blockchain and restore it in a fresh new environment

Tags: web3js, private-blockchain, poa, microsoft-azure, backup

Is there a way to backup the POA based ethereum private block-chain [created from microsoft azure POA template] and also restore it in a all new environment with out loosing any transactions & accounts?

Answer (score 1):

Zip/tarball the whole directory that has chain instance. This will include :

Accounts (keystore)
Block+Transactions (chaindata)

You can then start a node on any other machine with this directory.

In addition to the directory, there would be a genesis json, create a backup of that as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should ask an azure expert or post your question on azure website.I propose you explore the possibility of exporting the template as described here :

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-export-template

then backup and restore your VMs as described here
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/quick-backup-vm-portal